# Understanding My beauty was never in danger

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang, irish-english

The passage's from The Ferryman (play). What is the meaning of "My beauty was never in danger" in the passage, Also

is "Dunn's Ground" is a farming slang or something?

> MICHAEL. Here, Aunt Cait. Declan nearly got dragged through the bailer.
>   DECLAN: I did not.
>
> MICHAEL: We’re on Dunn’s Ground, bailing up, it’s all going fine when the
>   fecker stalls. This one, sticks his bake in the hot end, he’s poking round
>   and then he says, ‘Switch her on.’
>
> DIARMAID. Eeejit…
>
> DECLAN. Bull. My bake –
>
> MICHAEL. Listen now…
>
> DECLAN. My beauty was never in danger. Never in danger.
>
> MICHAEL. Then JJ fires whole thing up – (Makes noise of harvester.) and
>
> Declan sticks his head up with this look on his face like –

Comment: This doesn't look like a very suitable text for learning English! It's got a ***lot*** of slang that would be totally meaningless to most mainstream Anglophones. I just looked up ***bake*** to discover it's Irish slang for ***face***. So my guess is Declan has just stuck his face somewhere potentially "risky" (the engine compartment of a broken-down car?), but he's now facetiously saying his ***beauty = beautiful face*** was never in danger of being damaged, because he was always in control and knew exactly what he was doing.

Comment: ...oh, okay. Since they were ***bailing up***, I suppose ***the fecker*** must be a combine harvester or similar.

Comment: I assume that Dunn's Ground is the name of a field, and they were using a hay baler (don't know why it's spelled _bailer_).

Comment: @FFRM Wiktionary "fecker" :  (Ireland) fucker (term of abuse)

Comment: I guess "eejit" is phonetic spelling for "idiot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunn's Ground is capitalised. That is enough of hint that it is the name of a place. Probably a field.

They are making hay bails.  The bailer stops working.  Declan puts his head into the  machine. When JJ turns it back on (something that is very dangerous).

"My beauty" is a joking way and facetious way to say "My beautiful face".

This isn't the sort of slang you can use, unless you happen to be a mid-century Irish Farmer.